# positioning images at top right of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

My question is how can I place a image or span on top right of a div. I searched in google and found that

```
/* div that contains the image or span */
#div{ position:relative;}

/* image or span */
#span{ position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;}
```

But it is not what I finding. it does not take any space and all other things goes down or up of this. please give me the solution for this.

Comment: `#div` needs to contain non-positioned element(s) or `width: + height:` in order to have a width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `position:relative` and `absolute`

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <span>Right aligned</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:yellow
}
span{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    background:red
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t7Fby/1/)**

---

**METHOD 2**

Use `float:right` instead of `position:absolute`

```
.wrap{
    width:150px;
    background:yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
span{  
    background:red; float:right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/t7Fby/4/)**

Comment: ops sorry. its not working :( when i don't specifie the height of div this doesn't take space.

Comment: these methods are good...but aside tag is the best solution for my case. but I can use these methods next time :)

Answer (score 1):

or you can use float for easy option 
it take its space and positioned to its parent border corner 
so just add

```
float:right;
```

and 
then clear the float next to it

```
<div style="clear:right"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `#div` and `#span` instead of just mentioning them as `div` and `span`.

The **prefixes**:

- `#` is used to mention a ID name of a element.
- `.` is used to mention class name of elements.
- And nothing is used as prefix to mention a tag name.(simply, `div` or `span`)

Remove `#` prefix from your css style properties and your code will work.

---

An alternative way  is to go with `background-image` and use [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-position) to position a image top-right in a `div`.

```
div{background-image: url(yourImagePathHere); background-position: top right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if your first item in the `div` is the `span` or `img`.

**CSS:**

```
.d
{
display:block;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}

.s
{
display:block;
width:100px;;
height:100px;
float:right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="d"><span class="s"></span></div>
```